# How use wp_get_theme to modifiy singlepost.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How I use `wp_get_theme` to modify `singlepost.php`

```
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
function hs_set_post_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'hs_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

function hs_get_post_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'hs_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// Then add the following code inside your single post loop:
hs_get_post_views(get_the_ID());
hs_set_post_views(get_the_ID()); 

?>
```

I prepare to make a plugin , and want how can I edit singlepost.php to add
this code:

```
  hs_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution but if nothing else comes through in an answer you should be able to at least get something workable from this:     `add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) { if( is_single() ) { hs_set_post_views( get_the_ID() ); } return $content; } );`

Answer (score 0):

This could work, haven't validated, but just the idea:

```
add_action('loop_start', 'hs_set_post_views_loop');

function hs_set_post_views_loop($post_ID) {
   if( is_single() ) {
      hs_set_post_views($post_ID);
   }
}
```